# How to clear Buffer from BufferedInputStream in android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

for eg if client send "nick" then `BuffredInputStream` will read "nick" and then if client send "sanders" then `BuffredInputStream` will automatically append "nicksanders".

so how to clear old chunck from `BuffredInputStream` so that i always get new string every time from while reading from `BuffredInputStream`...

code:

```
if (bos1.available() > 0) {

int ij = bos1.read();

// msgLog is string
msgLog += new Character((char) ij).toString();

}
```

Comment: Did you try flush() method?

Comment: What you have stated isn't true. You will read "nick" and "sanders", or possibly both together, or parts of one and the other, but you will never read "nick" twice. Unclear what your actual problem is.

Comment: @Sandeep What `flush()` method?

Comment: @sandeep  flush method is only for outputstream not for inputstream...

Comment: @EJP  im not saying that it will read nick twice but when you send first send "nick" then "sanders" then it will append with previous string as stated in question above....

Comment: @NiravBhavsar Define 'append'. TCP/IP is a byte stream. One thing comes in after another. Everything is 'appended'. State your **real** problem.

Comment: ok @EJP is there any way to clear the previous byte stream when client send the another string....????

Comment: If you've already read it there is nothing to clear, and if you haven't already read it, read it. Your question doesn't make sense, and you have persistently failed to state your real problem despite having been asked to do so several times.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to flush inputstream , outputstream can be flushed because it implements Flushable interface.

Comment: Do you have some alternative? I'm using on bluetooth stream